# How to collect extra information in DetailView (CBV) from URL path?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Using FBV it is easy to grab information from the url, but I have no clue how to do the same thing with CBV.

with FBV:

1) urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [path('test/<int:test_number>/', views.testing, name='testing'),]
```

2) views.py:

```
    def testing(request, test_number):
        context = {'test_number': test_number}
        return render(request, 'testing.html', context)
```

3) template: 'testing.html'

```
    ...
    <p>Test #{{ test_number }}</p>
    ...
```

and the test number, which is written in url is shown on html page.

The question is, how can I do the same with CBV (DetailView in particular)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a subclass of [**`DetailView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) and override the [**`get_context_data()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test_number'] = self.kwargs['test_number']
        return context
```

and refer this new view in the urls.py file with the help of [**`as_view()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

```
urlpatterns = [path('test/<int:test_number>/', views.MyDetailView.as_view(), name='testing'), ]
```